# Kendo UI PanelBar Conditional Expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I need help with Kendo UI PanelBar.

I have 3 sections (3 Panel Bar's).

- Panel 1
- Panel 2
- Panel 3

It's a single expand mode. So you click on one panel then all other panels are collapsed and the one you clicked on expand.

However, I want to add a condition so that if there are invalid data in Panel 1, then you can't expand Panel 2 or 3.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an event to catch when an item of `panel bar` is expanded and you can use `e.preventDefault()`:

Like this:

```
 var onExpandEvt = function(e) {
    // access the expanded item via e.item (HTMLElement)
    // here you can put your verification......
    //if(validationFailed){
    //    e.preventDefault();
    //}
    // detach expand event handler via unbind()
    panelBar.data("kendoPanelBar").unbind("expand", onExpandEvt );
};

// attach expand event handler during initialization
var panelBar = $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
    expand: onExpandEvt 
});
```

Comment: Do I need to attach anything to the `Html.Kendo().PanelBar()` bit where I create the panel bar? The validation passes but then did not open the other panel.

Comment: The solution falls over on this line `panelBar.data("kendoPanelBar").unbind("expand", onExpandEvt );` because it can't read property `data` from undefined

Comment: It's "undefined" because your panelBar must have another name (by the way, you should post your code). When you have `var panelBar = $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar......`, you must ensure `#panelBar` is the id of your panel

Comment: The Id of my panel bar is `pannelbar`, `Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
.Name("pannelbar")`